# Check if value in the text input is visible completely or not with Cypress

Tags: javascript, frontend, cypress, e2e-testing

I want to write a Cypress test which checks if the inserted value in text box is completely visible or not. For example picture below passes the test because all 10 inserted characters are visible:

[image: Image passing the test since all the 10 characters are visible]

But the next picture fails the test, because only 6 of 10 inserted characters are visible:

[image: Image failing the test since only 6 of 10 inserted characters are visible]

Any idea how to implement it with Cypress?

**Note that in both cases the in put has the same value (1234567890), only in the second case, it is not visible because the input does not have enough space.**

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to validate a ten-digit number

See the script down below:

1.For 10 digit number:

```
cy.get('#<class-name-of-text-input>').contains(/^\d{10}$/)
```

2.For 10 digit number containing all 0-9 digits

```
cy.get('#<class-name-of-text-input>').contains(/^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d{10}$/)
```

Check [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) to validate the expression.

Comment: The fact is both inputs have the same value (1234567890). But as one of them has more padding it is not visible at the first glance in the second one, and it is annoying for the user. I want to be sure that this does not happen for any input in my project at least for 10 digits

Comment: `^` is for beginning. and `$` is for ending of string. "       1234567890" still fails

Comment: You didn't get my point. If the regex test passes, it passes for both and if it fails, it fails for the both situations, because in the both situations inputs have same value!

Comment: So your requirement is a 10 digit number or every number from 0-9?

Comment: I don't care what the value is, I just want it to be visible completely to the user and that user doesn't have to click in the input and use arrow buttons to see the hidden digits

Comment: @RezKesh hi, did you find a way to accomplish that?